# Check if same ID in 2 CSV have different names

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to write a program, which does the following in python.

1. read two CSV files
2. check if the matching IDs in CSV have a different name
3. output to another CSV ID, Names that don't match, and location

The first CSV file is the Mater CSV file, which contains all the correct information. It looks like the following

| ID | Name | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | John | London |
| 345 | Dave | New York |

The second CSV which want to comapre with the master looks like the following

| ID |  | Name | Marital Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | " " | John | Single |
| 345 | " " | Paul | Married |

I want to be able to check if the IDs with the corresponding name in the second CSV matches with the matching ID in the master CSV.

If not then output the ID, names where there is discrepancy and location to a new CSV.

This is what I have tried

```
with open(file1) as fp1:
    root = csv.reader(fp1)
    rows1 = {}
    for i in root:
        rows1[i[0]]=i
    if "id" in rows1:
        del rows1["id"]

with open(file2) as fp1:
    root = csv.reader(fp1)
    rows2 = {}
    for i in root:
        rows2[i[0]]=i
    if "id" in rows2:
        del rows2["id"]

   result = set(rows1.keys()).intersection(set(rows2.keys()))
```

The issue with this solution is that it just compares the ID and not the name data, which is in a different column as compared to the master data.

I am not sure how to read and compare the columns and output the data to a new CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps rather than this approach, I would use DataFrame joins to get the desired result.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, left_on=["ID", "Name2"], right_on=["ID", "Name"] ,how="left")
```

Where in Name2 is the Name column replicated

```
ID  Unnamed: 1  Name2   Marital Status  Name    Location
123 """ """     John    Single          John    London
345 """ """     Paul    Married
```

Now I can filter out the Name column with values resulting in the desired result you are looking for, get the desired columns and write it to a csv

```
df4 = df3[df3["Name"].isna() == True].filter(["ID", "Name2"])
df4.to_csv("results.csv")
```

Comment: doesn't this assume that all the IDs will be in the same order in the second CSV? I should have also mentioned that order maybe different in the second CSV as compared to the Master CSV.

Comment: No it doesn't assume so. You can give it a try

Comment: Would this not just output all the results in the `result.csv`? I just want to output the names which are different to from the master CSV @Akash

Comment: That is why we are filter for nulls. That would give you the data you are interested in.

Comment: If you look at the DataFrame output I have shown, ID 345 is what you are interested in if I am right. And that is exactly what you get after the filter condition

Comment: When I try to merge I get a key error on ID